# find all host posts with regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I have a string of hosts with ports, say "abs:1025, abs:1000, bca:1024".
How do I find all possible ports after "abs"?
This is what I tried so far

```
String hostName = host.substring(0, host.indexOf(":"));
String pattern = hostName +":([0-9]+)";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(javaNamingProviderUrl);
if(m.find()){
  hostAnyPort = m.group(1);
}
```

And I get only 1 possible host (1025), but I need both 1025 and 1000. Where is my mistake?

Comment: `if(m.find()){` -> `while(m.find()){`

Comment: Thank you, please write it as an answer, so I could choose it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main point is that you need to iterate through all the matches, replace `if` with `while`. See [the Java demo](https://ideone.com/uqnnKS):

```
String host = "abs:1025, abs:1000, bca:1024";
String hostName = host.substring(0, host.indexOf(":"));
String pattern = hostName +":([0-9]+)";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(host);
while(m.find()){
  System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Note that if your host name is known, you can hardcode it in the pattern: `pattern = "abs:([0-9]+)"`. If it can contain special chars (not probable though), you will need to use `Pattern.quote(hostName)`.

Also, since you are not using a Unicode-aware regex, you can replace `[0-9]` with `\d` (`pattern = hostName +":(\\d+)"`).

Comment: + then I'm storing ports in List

Comment: Yes, you can store them in a list, the demo is just to show how you get multiple matches.

Comment: But when Host name with port  is f.e. s-umw19-anxvvd:9000?

Comment: I wanted to also add that in case the host name should only be matched if preceded with whitespace, you can use `pattern = "(?<!\\S)abs:([0-9]+)"` (or `String pattern = "(?<!\\S)" + hostName +":([0-9]+)";`).